# clojure luminus global variable access into template

Tags: clojure, luminus

I'm trying to do a simple thing(at least for common frameworks) using Luminus and Selmer template but I can’t find a way to do it. I would like just to pass values to the base template, something like this:

file: `home.html`

```
{% extends "base.html" {:user {{ user }} } %}
​{% block content %}
...
​{% endblock %}
```

I know that we can do it using render a file, like this

`(render-file "html/base.html" {:user user})`

But it not looks right, it looks like a weird workaround.

My idea actually is to make some global variables to access anywhere of application like user session, but I didn’t find it in [luminus documentation](https://luminusweb.com/docs/html_templating.html)

Comment: Pardons if you're locked into the text-template solution, but, if not: there are better-trodden paths in Clojure. Data literals for element structures, so output encoding/escaping can be automatic. Snippets can be pure functions that compose with ordinary program logic. Immutable data lets you partly process a template and use the result as the starting point for many independent final customizations. Meanwhile, you avoid text templates' weak points:  yet another notation, with severe limits; repetition of effects in program code when you pass that limit, &amp;amp;amp; double encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, even when Selmer is cool, most of the web culture in Clojure turns around [Hiccup](https://github.com/weavejester/hiccup) as the template generator. You will use Hiccup with ClojureScript (Reagent - Re-frame) and that is another reason to switch to it. Probably you already have Hiccup installed, check it with:

```
lein deps :tree | grep hiccup
```

You will need to create a layout like [this one](https://github.com/aarkerio/ZentaurLMS/blob/master/src/clj/zentaur/hiccup/application_layout.clj). And uses it in a "controller" [like this](https://github.com/aarkerio/ZentaurLMS/blob/master/src/clj/zentaur/controllers/posts_controller.clj#L14) to build your HTML view.